# My list contains 4 numbers, I want generate 2 sub lists based on those numbers

Tags: python, list

### My code is

```
mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

for j in range(len(mylist)):

    print([mylist[j]]+[mylist[j+1]]+[mylist[j+2]])
```

Based on above code is I want to generate only 2 lists, I am getting output but how to avoid the Error.

### My expected output is

```
[0, -7, 4]
[-7, 4, -1]
```

### I am getting Error is

```
[0, -7, 4]
[-7, 4, -1]
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-27-fb3a67acb4b1> in <module>

      1 mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

      2 for j in range(len(mylist)):

----> 3     print([mylist[j]]+[mylist[j+1]]+[mylist[j+2]])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Both `mylist[j+1]` and `mylist[j+2]` *will* go out of bounds in your loop.

Comment: Note that you can produce the sublists a lot more simply by *slicing*: `print(mylist[j : j+3])`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get a sublist of three consecutive elements from the list? As @Someprogrammerdude said, you loop over the length of your list.

Comment: How about `mylist[:-1]` and `mylist[1:]` ?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to do this via a loop as that is part of the requirements, or can you use slice notation? If you can use slice notation this is the way to go in my opinion. See comment by @Goku for details

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that when j reaches the last iteration of the loop, mylist[j+2] goes out of range because there is no element at the index j+2. To avoid this error, you can adjust the loop range to stop at len(mylist) - 2. Here's the corrected code:

```py
mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

for j in range(len(mylist) - 2):
    print([mylist[j]] + [mylist[j+1]] + [mylist[j+2]])
```

This way, the loop will only run until the third-to-last element of `mylist`, and you won't encounter an `IndexError`. The output will be:

```
[0, -7, 4]
[-7, 4, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

No loops are required, just slice:

```
mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

mylist1 = mylist[0 : 3]
mylist2 = mylist[1 : 4]

print(mylist1, mylist2)
```

[0, -7, 4] [-7, 4, -1]

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure if you only are dealing with 4 element lists, then indexing the list would be best and would require no loops.

```
mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

generate_lists = mylist[:-1], mylist[1:]
```

Or if you wanted to create a function:

```
def generate_lists(l):
    return l[:-1], l[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because when `j` reaches its maximum value (which is `len(mylist) - 1`), the expression `mylist[j+2]` exceeds the bounds of the list. To avoid this error and generate only 2 lists, you can modify the loop to iterate up to the second-to-last element in the list. Here's the modified code:

```
mylist = [0, -7, 4, -1]

for j in range(len(mylist) - 2):
    print([mylist[j], mylist[j+1], mylist[j+2]])
```

This code will generate the expected output without raising an `IndexError`.

**Output:**

```
[0, -7, 4]
[-7, 4, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

hi it is showing index not found error because if u see tht at one point j will be equal to 3 and so [mylist[3]]+[mylist[3+1]]+[mylist[3+2]]). yea so there will be no number at the index 4 or 5 or so on. So the solution to this is:

```
list = [0, -7, 4, -1] 
for j in range(len(mylist)): 
    if j == 2:
        break  # This will break the loop and give u ur expected outcome. 
    print( [mylist[j]] + [mylist[j+1]] + [mylist[j+2]] )
```